# loading a file with a path like "../input"

Tags: python, python-import

I'm new to coding and python,

I was wondering what the ../ meant in

```
train = pd.read_csv("../input/train.csv"),
```

my cd is C:\Users\user

and there is a folder 'input' with the train.csv file in there but this code gives an error -

> File b'../input/train.csv' does not exist

how would I read that file using the code above?

Comment: `../` means move up to the parent folder. Wher is the full path that you expect `train.csv` to be located? The path you are specifying is `C:\Users\input\train.csv`

Comment: did you try replacing linux style paths with windows style ones. since ti does look like you're working with windows

Comment: ah right, thanks, I was working with windows